# print different value inside column on second appearance of the same row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where I print data from database. and sometimes there can be more than one appearance of the same name. 
[image]
As you can see there is same name with different process. Here is my table:

```
  <table>
    <?php
    $result = getPhData();
        echo '
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Staff ID</th>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Nicknames</th>
                    <th>Employment type</th>
                    <th>Dept:Prod/Other</th>
                    <th>Number of projects</th>
                    <th>Many projects?</th>
                    <th>Ratio per project</th>
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>Process</th>
                    <th>Leader</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php ';                        
    ?>
        <tbody>
          <?php     
                $count = 0;
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {   
                        $staffid=$row["staff_id"];
                        $longnm=$row["longname"];
                        $usrnm=$row["username"];
                        $user_type=$row["user_type"];
                        $number=$row["number"];
                        $title=$row["title"];
                        $code=$row["code"];
                        $process=$row["process"];
                        $role=$row["role"];
                        $ratio=1/$number;
            ?>
            <tr valign="top">
              <td><?php echo $staffid; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $longnm; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $usrnm; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $user_type; ?></td>
              <td>
                  <?php if($code=='OPD'){ echo "Others";}
                        else{echo "Prod";}
                  ?>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $number; ?></td>
                <td>  
                  <?php if($number==1){ echo "First Occurrence";}
                        else{echo "Duplicate";}
                  ?>
                </td>
              <td><?php echo $ratio; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
              <td>
                    <?php if($process == NULL) 
                    { echo $role; }
                    else{ echo $process; }
                    ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <?php if($role == 'ld') 
                    { echo "Yes"; }
                    else{ echo "";}?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                    $count++;}

                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

What I want is to print "duplicate" when same id appears second/third etc time in the table. How can I achieve this through php? Thanks

Comment: Normally I'm first to advocate handling these sorts of issues in application code, but here I actually think I'd do it in the query. That said, in your loop, you could just store the current row's value. If the next row's value equals that stored value, echo 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# In this array we will store first ids
$dataIds = array();
<table>
<?php
$result = getPhData();
    echo '
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Staff ID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Nicknames</th>
                <th>Employment type</th>
                <th>Dept:Prod/Other</th>
                <th>Number of projects</th>
                <th>Many projects?</th>
                <th>Ratio per project</th>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Process</th>
                <th>Leader</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php ';                        
?>
    <tbody>
      <?php     
            $count = 0;
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {   

                    $staffid=$row["staff_id"];
                    $duplicate = "";

                    if (!in_array($staffid, $dataIds)) {
                        array_push($dataIds, $stafid);
                    } else {
                        $duplicate = "Duplicate";
                    }

                    $longnm=$row["longname"]. "($duplicate)";
                    $usrnm=$row["username"];
                    $user_type=$row["user_type"];
                    $number=$row["number"];
                    $title=$row["title"];
                    $code=$row["code"];
                    $process=$row["process"];
                    $role=$row["role"];
                    $ratio=1/$number;
        ?>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td><?php echo $staffid; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $longnm; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $usrnm; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $user_type; ?></td>
          <td>
              <?php if($code=='OPD'){ echo "Others";}
                    else{echo "Prod";}
              ?>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $number; ?></td>
            <td>  
              <?php if($number==1){ echo "First Occurrence";}
                    else{echo "Duplicate";}
              ?>
            </td>
          <td><?php echo $ratio; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
          <td>
                <?php if($process == NULL) 
                { echo $role; }
                else{ echo $process; }
                ?>
          </td>
          <td>
                <?php if($role == 'ld') 
                { echo "Yes"; }
                else{ echo "";}?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
                $count++;}

            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the duplicate will be shown beside the full name.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make a second array in your while adding every id used after for check if this id is already in the table so

```
<?php     
            $count = 0;
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                $parsedId = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {   
                    if(in_array($row['id'], $parsedId))
                       //DUPLICATE
                    else
                       array_push($parsedId, $row['id']);
                    /*CODE */
                 }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with an array. Collect ID of the employee/persons on some array and then check if is there ID [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
<?php
     $staffs = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $staffid = $row["staff_id"];

          $staffs[] = $staffid;

         //// your table code.

         <td>  
              <?php if(in_array($row["staff_id"], $staffs)){ 
                       echo "First Occurrence";
                    } else{
                      echo "Duplicate";
                    }
              ?>
         </td>
     }

     ?>
```

Another way, you can do it with `SQL` query. With IF THEN statement.